# How do I make the annotations look like the current location indicator?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I am trying to customize the annotations on the map, and instead of pins I want the annotations to look like the current location indicator. How would I do this? Any advice would be great!

Comment: Just a round dot? Create an image for it and then have `viewForAnnotation` create a `MKAnnotationView` and set its `image` property.

Comment: See [Defining a Custom Annotation Object](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW2) in the _Location and Maps Programming Guide._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can use custom annotation object which extends MKPointAnnotation. But if you just need to change pin image you can avoid subclassing and just implement this method

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    let identifier = "MyPin"

    if annotation.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }

    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)

    if let annotationView = annotationView {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation
    } else {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "myPinImage")
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

So it's enough for you to find correct image and replace pins with it. 
But if you want to follow possible changes of default currentLocation image you can reuse default view

```
let annotationView = mapView.viewForAnnotation(mapView.userLocation());
```

Comment: @user6032625 - He meant `if let` with `=` rather than `==`.